# Removing/Hiding a li href link within a DIV

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to hide/remove a Link (team.aspx) within a drop down menu which will be added back in later on. Heres my code:

```
<div id="nav_menu">
<ul id="nav">
    <li class="current"><a href="home.aspx">HOME</a> </li>
    <li><a href="iam.aspx">I AM A...</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="whoweare.aspx">WHO WE ARE</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="profile.aspx">OUR EXPERIENCE</a> </li>
        <li><a href="team.aspx">OUR TEAM</a></li>
        <li><a href="mission.aspx">MISSION, VALUES, VISION</a></li>
        <li><a href="strength.aspx">STRENGTHENING COMMUNITIES</a></li>
        <li><a href="stories.aspx">WHERE STORIES ARE MADE</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

First, I tried to remove the `<li>` using pseudo which worked however it removed all the `<li>` in each second position:
 `nav li ul li:nth-child(2) { display: none; }`

Next, I tried it with jQuery which I know I'm missing something, I need help please:

```
(function($) {  
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#nav li ul li:has(a[href='team'])").remove();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You have too many `<ul>` and not enough `</ul>` as far as I can tell. You may also be missing a `</li>`. Please make sure you have valid HTML markup.

Comment: To format your code properly in the question, highlight it, then click the "Code Sample" button above the edit area. It looks like **`{ }`**.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a typo in the question, but you have a `{` where you should have a `[`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#nav li ul li:has(a[href='team'])").remove();
    // -------------------^
});
```

Aside from that, it's hard to know the correct answer without seeing your markup.

---

**EDIT:**

If you're going to use the [`attribute-equals-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector, it needs to be an exact match.

So this:

```
$("#nav li ul li:has(a[href='team'])").remove();
```

should be:

```
$("#nav li ul li:has(a[href='team.aspx'])").remove();
```

or as an alternative, you could use the [`attribute-starts-with-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) .

```
$("#nav li ul li:has(a[href^='team'])").remove();
```

Comment: Thanks buddy I came up with this: $(document).ready(function(){
$('#nav li a[href*=team]').remove();
 
});

Comment: @Kmack: You're welcome. That one uses the [`attribute-contains-selector`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/). Keep in mind that both the `starts-with` and `contains` will do partial matches.